# Can I delete Multiple delete in sequelize.js(Node js)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, destroy

**I want to delete multiple delete row in my sql which are createdBy is older than ane week **

```
Model.destroy({ where: { createdBy : date.Now < date.Now + 604800000}})
```

Can I do this from above code..?

Comment: What's the problem with your code ?

Comment: its not working.

Comment: Are u sure of the condition passed to your delete query? try it with the find !

Comment: if you know how to get one week older entries please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it:

```
var orders = await db.order.destroy({
        where: {
            createdAt: {
               [Op.lte] : (new Date() -  7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000   )
            }
        }
    })
```

Its working properly.

Comment: If you have to regularly delete one weeks old record, I would suggest doing it in MySQL itself by creating an event rather than depending on Cron, Node.js, Sequelize to do it.
Php myadmin provides great UI for it. 

DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM loginHists WHERE createdAt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 Model.findAll({
  where: {
    createdBy: {
      $lte: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()
    }
  }
})
```